# Playing one mp3 file (in loop) in OS X 10.5 or higher

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to play an mp3 file, on repeat, on OS X 10.5 or higher?

Please reply with a code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url byReference:YES];
[sound setLoops:YES];
[sound play];
// Later, when finished with sound
[sound release];
```

Comment: Thanks! for anyone interested, if you need to load the file from the application bundle: NSSound *sound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"FILENAME.mp3"];